# Magento 2 - Sort by Brand and Position?

Tags: magento2, sorting, sort, sort-by-position

Is it possible to sort by A the Brand alphabetically and then B by Position Programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, It is possible to sort by A the Brand alphabetically and then B by Position. As you can see this functionality is already implemented in Amasty's extension.

https://amasty.com/shop-by-brand-for-magento-2.html

Answer (score 0):

using collection you can sort and filter everthing.
Here's the link to filter by attribute: https://www.mageplaza.com/devdocs/how-get-product-collection-magento-2.html

And here the sort by: `$productCollection->addAttributeToSort('update_at', 'DESC')`

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

**Yes, I am user for alphabetically shop by brand extension.please try to this extension**

https://github.com/zekinah/magento2-AdvancedSortby

https://github.com/boolfly/brand